# Having issues combining HAVING with WHERE on a very simple QUERY

Tags: postgresql

[image: I have the following simple excercise]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT group_id, player_id as winner_id
/* 
,sum(M1.first_score + M2.second_score), sum(M2.first_score + M1.second_score)
*/

FROM players as P1

LEFT JOIN matches as M1 
ON M1.first_player = P1.player_id

LEFT JOIN matches as M2
ON M2.second_player = P1.player_id

LEFT JOIN matches as M3
ON M3.first_player = P1.player_id

LEFT JOIN matches as M4
ON M4.second_player = P1.player_id


--WHERE P1.player_id is not null /*or P2.player_id is not null*/

GROUP BY group_id, P1.player_id

/*
HAVING 
sum(M1.first_score + M2.second_score) > sum(M2.first_score + M1.second_score)
OR
sum(M3.first_score + M4.second_score) > sum(M4.first_score + M3.second_score)
*/

ORDER BY group_id ASC, player_id ASC
```

The results that I am getting are:

1,30
 1,45
 1,65
 2,20
 2,50
 3,40

I know I am missing something very obvious as usual

This is my most recent

```
attempt

-- write your code in PostgreSQL 9.4
SELECT 
group_id,  player_id as winner_id

/* 
,sum(M1.first_score + M2.second_score), sum(M2.first_score + M1.second_score)
*/

FROM players as P1

LEFT JOIN matches as M1 
ON M1.first_player = P1.player_id

LEFT JOIN matches as M2
ON M2.second_player = P1.player_id

LEFT JOIN matches as M3
ON M3.first_player = P1.player_id

LEFT JOIN matches as M4
ON M4.second_player = P1.player_id


GROUP BY group_id, P1.player_id, M1,M2,M3,M4

/*
HAVING 
(M1 is not null) OR (M2 is not null) OR (M3 is not null) OR (M4 is not null)
*/

/*
HAVING 
sum(M1.first_score + M2.second_score) > sum(M2.first_score + M1.second_score)
OR
sum(M3.first_score + M4.second_score) > sum(M4.first_score + M3.second_score)
*/

ORDER BY group_id ASC
/*, player_id DESC
*/
```

How can I fix the query so that I can get the expected results

Comment: You have a list of what players are in which group, now you need to find the total score for each player.  Then combine the two results to get which player had the highest score in their group.  I'd probably ditch the `HAVING` statements and use `RANK()` or `ROWNUM()` with a `PARTITION`

Comment: I didn't do the downvoting but I guess it's because you posted a screenshot rather than a textual representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any PostgreSQL background but lets see if this works:

I would start this by simplifying it, by writing a query that first returns the total score by player:

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
FROM (
  SELECT first_player as player_id, first_score as score
  FROM matches
  UNION ALL
  SELECT second_player, second_score
  FROM matches
)
GROUP BY player_id
```

Now, join that dataset to players to find the groups:

```
SELECT w.player_id, p.group_id, w.score
FROM
(
  SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
  FROM (
    SELECT first_player as player_id, first_score as score
    FROM matches
    UNION ALL
    SELECT second_player, second_score
    FROM matches
  )
  GROUP BY player_id
) as w
inner join players p
on p.player_id = w.player_id
```

Now we have all players, their total score and their group. We want to identify the winner by group? We can use [ranking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) functions to do this:

```
SELECT 
w.player_id, 
p.group_id, 
w.score, 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.group_id ORDER BY score DESC) as group_placement
FROM
(
  SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
  FROM (
    SELECT first_player as player_id, first_score as score
    FROM matches
    UNION ALL
    SELECT second_player, second_score
    FROM matches
  )
  GROUP BY player_id
) as w
inner join players p
on p.player_id = w.player_id
```

Now we just pick out the top ones in each group (rank = 1) using `WHERE`

```
  SELECT 
  player_id, 
  group_id
  FROM
  (
      SELECT 
      w.player_id, 
      p.group_id, 
      w.score, 
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.group_id ORDER BY score DESC) as group_placement
      FROM
      (
        SELECT player_id, SUM(score) score
        FROM (
          SELECT first_player as player_id, first_score as score
          FROM matches
          UNION ALL
          SELECT second_player, second_score
          FROM matches
        )
        GROUP BY player_id
      ) as w
      inner join players p
      on p.player_id = w.player_id
    ) as gp
    WHERE group_placement = 1
```

Looks complicated? yes, but you can see have the final result is provided bit by bit. Each step of this is a 'subtable' and you can run and observe the data at each point.

Comment: Yeah I should've left off the final `WHERE` :). I almost always just provide hints in comments exactly as you have. As it is I can't test my answer so it may not work so there may yet be some work required. So... how much you want to bet this question is just abandoned by the OP because they either lost interest or couldn't understand the answer :/

Comment: I have a follow-up question on the solution. Will the above solution return the last row in the desired output ? " 3 40" ? Since 40 did not play in any match, the inner join in the second step will exclude player id - 40 from the calculations. Thus, a left outer join on players table would bring in 40 for group 3

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez as I predicted, you abandoned this question.